# How to get an HTTP response with specific port using http.client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http.client

I tried to get a page contents of the following URL

```
http://username:5000/check/e9549df676ecca6344ad8ba068d05a6d
```

So I tried to write the following script but with no success

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("username",5000)
conn.request("GET", "/check/e9549df676ecca6344ad8ba068d05a6d")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.read())
```

When I run the script it would just hang, could anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Try to read the response in chunks.

Comment: @scenox there is not much data on that page and even if I try to get `r1.status` it won't succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address you are trying to connect to uses HTTP. You are connecting via HTTP**S** to the server using `HTTPSConnection`. If the server does not accept an HTTPS connection on port 5000, an error is thrown as the library does not automatically downgrade or change the protocol.

Try to change [`http.client.HTTPSConnection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection) to [`http.client.HTTPConnection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection).